# bad substitution running ${ls ... | sed ...} with bash

Tags: bash

I got the following error:

```
./assemblyDB.116.las
test.sh: line 9: ${ls $filename | sed 's/assemblyDB.//' | sed 's/.las//'}: bad substitution
```

and this is the script:

```
for filename in $(find . -type f -name "assemblyDB.*.las"); do
   echo $filename
   no=${ls $filename | sed 's/assemblyDB.//' | sed 's/.las//'}
   echo $no
done
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the braces?  Also quote your variables.

Comment: See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/135943)

Answer (score 26):

`${ ... }` (curly braces) marks several sorts of [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073), the simplest of which is just expanding the value of a variable. The stuff inside braces in your code isn't a valid parameter name, or any other expansion, so the shell complains.

You seem to want command substitution instead, for that, the syntax is `$( ... )` (regular parenthesis).

Also, the `ls` in `ls $filename | sed...` seems a bit unnecessary, the variable expands to your filename, and `ls` just passes it through. You could just use `echo "$filename" | sed ...` instead.

That said, you could do those modifications directly in the shell:

```
no="${filename/assemblyDB.}"   # remove first match
no="${no/.las}"
```

or, using the standard operators:

```
no="${filename#assemblyDB.}"   # remove from start of string
no="${no%.las}"                # remove from end of string
```

If you do run `sed`, you may want to note that `.` matches any character in regular expressions, so it would be more correct to quote it with a backslash. Also you can give one `sed` instance both commands: `sed -e 's/assemblyDB\.//' -e 's/\.las//'`.

And then `for filename in $(find . -type f -name "assemblyDB.*.las"); do` has all the issues [parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) has, mostly the fact that whitespace and wildcards in file names will break it. In ksh/Bash/zsh, you could do that whole loop in the shell:

```
shopt -s globstar         # in Bash
for filename in **/assemblyDB.*.las; do
    ...
```

Comment: @Jesse_b, yes, but if your shell has `<<<`, it probably has `${var/pat/repl}` too. If you do run sed, you could just give both rules to one `sed` instance: `sed -e 's/assemblyDB\.//' -e 's/\.las//'`

Comment: Just wanted to point out UUOE ;)

Answer (score 1):

Command substitution (line 3)

```
for filename in $(find . -type f -name "assemblyDB.*.las"); do
   echo $filename
   no=$(ls $filename | sed 's/assemblyDB.//' | sed 's/.las//')
   echo $no
done
```

is equivalent, as already pointed out, to (line 3, no `ls`)

```
for filename in $(find . -type f -name "assemblyDB.*.las"); do
   echo $filename
   no=$(echo $filename | sed 's/assemblyDB.//' | sed 's/.las//')
   echo $no
done
```

or shorter (line 4 gone, now echo directly)

```
for filename in $(find . -type f -name "assemblyDB.*.las"); do
   echo $filename
   echo $filename | sed 's/assemblyDB.//' | sed 's/.las//'
done
```

and the sed command can be reduced to (line 3)

```
for filename in $(find . -type f -name "assemblyDB.*.las"); do
   echo $filename
   echo $filename | sed 's/assemblyDB.//;s/.las//'
done
```

or maybe extract the middle part with sed: (still line 3)

```
for filename in $(find . -type f -name "assemblyDB.*.las"); do
   echo $filename
   echo $filename | sed -r 's/.*assemblyDB.(.*).las/\1/'" 
done
```

now find-iterator instead of for-iterator: (line 1 to 3, 4 gone)

```
find . -type f -name "assemblyDB.*.las" -printf "%f\n" -exec sh -c "
   echo {} | sed -r 's/.*assemblyDB.(.*).las/\1/'"  ";"

assemblyDB.11.las
11
assemblyDB.9.las
9
assemblyDB.10.las
10
```

If your filenames are in such or a similar order, the following might work too:

```
for i in {8..12} ; do ls assemblyDB.$i.las && echo $i ; done 2>/dev/null

assemblyDB.9.las
9
assemblyDB.10.las
10
assemblyDB.11.las
11
```

(8 and 12 included, to demonstrate missing files in the sequence).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `${}` use backticks `` ` `` [The button below Escape on your keyboard.]

Comment: Please don't use backticks.  Use command substitution.  `$( ... )`

Comment: Can you explain why back ticks are bad?

Comment: They are outdated, they are hard to read, they don't nest, and they can **always** be replaced by parenthesis command substitution.  Additionally they are hard to place into inline code blocks on most markdown languages :)

Comment: Yeah, that is right. But in regards to this question where did my answer go wrong??

Comment: You suggested using backticks.

Comment: @Jesse_b There's plenty of reasons not to use backticks, but the inability to nest them is not one of them: ```echo `echo \`echo hello\`` ```. Yes, it requires escaping, but that just means it's not as easy to nest as `$(...)`, not that it's impossible.